# Regex to Convert UPPER_CASE to kCamelCase

Tags: regex, sublimetext

Currently, constants in my code are in upper case and separated by underscores, but I would like to change them to be in camel case preceded by a "k." (ex: TICKS_PER_INCH -> kTicksPerInch) What regex can I use to do this? (I'm using Sublime Text.)

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't remember...it's been months since I tried to write a regex to do this but without any experience in regexes I spent a lot of time on this without success. I decided changing the code style wasn't a priority so I moved on with writing the software. The other day I decided to ask someone on stackoverflow how it would be done because I'm tired of seeing constants shouting at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime uses the [Boost PCRE library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) for Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions. Looking through that link should help you in the future.

---

You'll need to do this in two steps. To assist with the second step, install the [`Case Conversion`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net).

First, select `Find -> Replace...`. To the left of the `Find What:` field, make sure the first four buttons are selected - ***Regular Expression***, ***Case Sensitive***, ***Whole Word***, and ***Wrap***. To the left of the `Replace With:` field, select ***Highlight Matches***.

Now for the `Find What:` regex. Assuming you have no variables that are a single capital letter, you want to search for `(\b[A-Z_]+\b)`: ***`\b`*** matches word boundaries and ***`[A-Z_]+`*** matches strings containing one or more capital letters and underscores. Surrounding everything in parentheses assigns the whole pattern to a single match variable, which we'll use later. To do some quality control, before replacing with anything hit the `Find All` button and scroll through your code to ensure that everything that's selected is what you want.

Once you're satisfied you're finding everything, the replacement regex is easy: `K_$1`. This adds `K_` to the beginning of every match (the match variable `$1`), so `FOO_BAR` becomes `K_FOO_BAR`.

On to the second part - camel casing. Go to `Find -> Find...` and use `(\b[A-Z_]+\b)` and the same options as before (***Regular Expression***, ***Case Sensitive***, ***Whole Word***, and ***Wrap***), then hit `Find All` to select all your constants. Double-check you've selected everything you want to and nothing you don't want to, then go to `Edit -> Convert Case -> camelCase` and `K_FOO_BAR` should become `kFooBar`.

---

Regex actually aren't that hard if you know which flavor you're supposed to use, and you have a good reference, like the one linked above. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! The link you gave me is a great resource and the method you posted works perfectly.